# DatePicker ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native

Как мне оставить только месяц например, чтобы не отображались дни и год.
format = "dddd" пробовал, ошибку выдает.

[DatePicker](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker)

Comment: format = "MMMM"

Comment: так не работает.Выводит и год и месяц и день